# Drupal 7 Search api Solr - 400 Bad request on indexing or cleaning

Tags: drupal, solr

Trying to clean the index:
Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException: '400' Status: Bad Request em Apache_Solr_Service->_sendRawPost() (linha 364 de /home/mercado/public_html/sites/all/libraries/SolrPhpClient/Apache/Solr/Service.php

Trying to index itens:
Couldn't index items. Check the logs for details.
Log Says:
An error occurred while indexing: '400' Status: Bad Request.

Im using the latest release for apache solr and solrPHPclient. Everything seens ok, im using the schema.xml from the module and the module checks the solr server ok...

There is no log file in my path/to/solr/example/logs

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and realized I had the copied the wrong configuration files to the /Applications/apache-solr-3.6.1/example/solr/conf directory. Once I copied the correction version from sites/all/modules/search_api_solr/solr-conf/3.x it started to index properly.

Answer (score -3):

Check your Apache solar is running on your server

Comment: You need to add more info than that - particularly seeing as though the server would not return a 400 if it wasn't running.